# How to Parse the first Property even if the Json is not valid?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am parsing tons of different jsons which only have the first Property in common.
Depending on the value of this first property I parse the json into different object and also handle possible error differently. However it happens that the json is not valid but I still want to know the value of the first property (as long as this is valid) so I can handle the parsing error. I was wondering if this is possible with `Json.Net`. Of course I assume that at least the first property is valid, something like this for example:

```
{
   "parsingType":"sometype",
   "someothervalue":123,
   "someval"123,
}
```

I tried the following but since the exception is thrown when using `.Parse` I get no result:

```
JToken jtoken = JToken.Parse(json);
var theValueIWantToGet = jtoken["parsingType"].Value<string>();
```

Comment: Since you are interested in only this value, why bother parsing it at all? Just do a string search. It will be faster too.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the JSON? Or rather where do you get it from? If it comes from your own app or service, you can add `TypeNameHandling.All` and `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple` with the `JsonSerializerSettings` which allows the Deserializer to recognize and find the right type in your assembly.

Comment: Try using a JsonReader as shown in [How can I deserialize an invalid json ? Truncated list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36576928/10263)

Comment: Well I am not sure how to get the value without json.net since I get a string and will use the `StringEnumConverter` to get a enum out of it. The json does come from an external service where I do not have any control. I really need ony the first property at first (and later I parse the rest if possible). I could cut of the string at the first `,` and replace that with a `}` and parse then the value with a `StringEnumConverter` but I thought that there is an easier solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think any parsing engine parses json partially. You will have to parse your json string by yourself if parser fails

```
        string json = "{ \"parsingType\":\"sometype\", \"someothervalue\":12}";
        var props = json.Replace('{',' ').Replace('}',' ').Split(',').ToList();
        if (props.Count > 0)
        {
            var firstProp = props[0].Split(':');
            var propName = firstProp[0];
            var propVal = firstProp[1];

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`JsonReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) (probably [`JsonTextReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) as the concrete type) to parse the JSON as a stream, a bit like `XmlReader`. So for example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText("test.json")))
        {            
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.TokenType);                
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the JSON you've provided, that will give output of:

```
StartObject

PropertyName
parsingType
String
sometype
PropertyName
someothervalue
Integer
123

Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException [...]
```

So if you always expect there to be a start object, then a property name, then a string property value, you could easily validate that that's the case and extract the property value.