# JsonConvert.Deserialize with truncated JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to allow users to preview truncated JSON for large files. For example, I want to allow users to see the first 100 lines of (formatted) JSON without loading the whole file into memory and transferring it.

So on the server, we stream in the first X bytes of the file, which obviously will yield truncated JSON. But I'd like to close off any open elements so that a JSON viewer is able to show the preview.

I was hoping that I could do this:

```
var partialJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(partialJsonString);
var completeJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(partialJson);
```

But `.DeserializeObject()` throws an `Unterminated String` exception due to the truncation.

Is there a way to get `JsonConvert` to deserialize truncated JSON, and if not, are there alternative solutions?

Comment: what are they previewing it in?  why not just use the `partialJsonString` formatted to your end UI?

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with `react-json-inspector`, but it's expecting complete (valid) JSON too, which is why I was hoping I could handle it on the backend. Otherwise, it's just a very long, unpretty, single line of JSON text. I don't see any other frontend viewers that would handle truncated JSON either.

Comment: You can try utilizing `Json(Text)Reader` / `Json(Text)Writer` classes.

Comment: Thanks guys, [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577605/213902) got me what I needed.