# Json.net - how to "fix" incomplete JSON?

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I have some incomplete JSON payload (from, say, an HTTP connection that failed mid-transfer). The part that was downloaded is valid, but the download can break at any point.

Using Json.NET, **how can I extrapolate the rest of the JSON payload?**
.
.
.
Okay, just kidding.

What I really want is (using Json.NET) to transform the chunk that I have into valid JSON, as much as possible.

The format of the Json payload is unknown a priori.

Here's an example of a broken Json
- watch your step when reading, it ends abruptly:

```
var broken = @"[
    {'key':'value'},
    {'Tables': [
        {
            'TableName': 'Table_0',
            'Columns': [
                {
                    'ColumnName': 'Enabled',
                    'DataType': 'String',
                }
            ],
            'Rows': [
                [
                    'False',
                    'getuser'
";
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Json.net, but your question would depend on whether you know the expected json structure or not. If you do know how something like the 'Tables' object looks like, you could pass it to something like a serializer / parser and leave the rest on default.

Comment: Updated question. The format can be anything.

Comment: Looks a bit like [How can I deserialize an invalid json ? Truncated list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36576928/3744182).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I need to get low-level with Json.NET, I end up using the stream readers/writers.

Turns out the `JsonTextWriter` has a magic property `AutoCompleteOnClose` that does the trick of adding any 'pending' 'end tokens' when the writer is closed.

```
var broken = @"[
    {'key':'value'},
    {'Tables': [
        {
            'TableName': 'Table_0',
            'Columns': [
                {
                    'ColumnName': 'Enabled',
                    'DataType': 'String',
                }
            ],
            'Rows': [
                [
                    'False',
                    'getuser',
                    {'fdsa':
";

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    var wr = new JsonTextWriter(sw) 
    { 
        AutoCompleteOnClose = true, //simple - just ask the writer to fill in any missing closing tokens
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented 
    };
    using (wr)
    {
        using (var rdr = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(broken)) { CloseInput = true })
        {
            try
            {
                wr.WriteToken(rdr);
            }
            catch { /* swallow the read error and keep on trucking */ }
        }
    } //json writer is closed now
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
}
```

This is the output it yields:

```
[
  {
    "key": "value"
  },
  {
    "Tables": [
      {
        "TableName": "Table_0",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "ColumnName": "Enabled",
            "DataType": "String"
          }
        ],
        "Rows": [

          [
            "False",
            "getuser",
            {
              "fdsa": null
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```