# How to deserialize fields from incomplete JSON in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have incomplete JSON strings so the JSON is invalid, e.g.:

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": "John",
    "Surname": "Smith",
    "BadAnswers": ["Answer1", "Answer2"],
    "CorrectAnswers": ["Answer3", "Answer4", "Answer5", "Answ
```

From this JSON I need to extract `ID`, `Name` and `BadAnswers` fields which are complete. I can't just deserialize this string using json.net because JSON is invalid.
Real case contains much more complex JSON with nested objects, lists, etc. but the idea the same.

So the main question is **how to extract complete fields from partially completed and thus invalid JSON?**

*UPDATE 1.* I can't make JSON valid by hand because it may be truncated at the random place not only at the place shown in the example. The only thing I know is that all required properties are present in truncated JSON. But if there any way to *make JSON valid* using json.net or any other library it would be a nice solution.

*UPDATE 2.* However there is already an answer to the question it is a quite low-level solution and requires a lot of manual work to manipulate with tokens and do not generalize well to different JSON formats.

> The solution for you might be to use a JsonReader

For example, consider more complex JSON like this one:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "completed": true,
            "id": 0
        },
        {
            "completed": true,
            "id": 1
        }
    ],
    "someProperty": false,
    "anotherProperty": true,
    "requiredIdProperty": 1,
    "requiredArrayProperty": [
        {
            "nestedIdPropery": 0,
            "nestedBoolProperty": true
        },
        {
            "nestedIdPropery": 1,
            "nestedBoolProperty": false
        }
    ],
    "truncatedObject": {
        "firstProperty": 990,
        "secondProperty": 0,
        "thirdPrope
```

In this case, there are no problems with extracting `requiredIdProperty` using `JsonReader` but extracting `requiredArrayProperty` is painful because I need to manually handle all JSON tokens like `JsonToken.ArrayStart` and others. Said again, **real case may and will contain much more complex JSON with more nested objects and arrays**.

The ideal solution I'm looking for is to map JSON to a POCO class ignoring everything starting from the first invalid token or something like this.

Comment: Can you try to make the json valid and deserialize it ? Like adding the missing chars at the end of json

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576928/how-can-i-deserialize-an-invalid-json-truncated-list-of-objects

Comment: That is called coding not painful. When you have invalid format you can not count for common libs. This mean you have to create your own code. If that is low level and painful. A generic operations suggested by @senerth seems to be good fit to recover the file. Its quite basic stack operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for you might be to use a JsonReader

```
using (FileStream s = File.Open("broken.json", FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // deserialize only when there's "{" character in the stream
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            //Your code 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution will work, however, I'm looking for some higher-level one. Check _update 2_ section in question please and see if you can help with it too.

Comment: I have been searching for such solution for years, nice and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't just add the two missing characters to the string and then deserialize?

I know this seems too obvious but just incase:

jsonString+="]}";

Then deserialize jsonString.

Comment: I can't complete json myself because it may be truncated at the random place. So I need to _revalidate_ json which is not so easy task.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense.