# Correct invalid json for use with Json.Net

Tags: json.net

I have some JSON which I have no control over it's from a third-party supplier and the quotes are not handled properly resulting in malformed JSON. I have asked them to correct it but in the meantime, I would like to be able to use it.

```
var json = "{
    "news": {
        "headline": "Headline",
        "items: [
            {
                "title": "title1",
                "description": "description1",
            },
            {
                "title": "title2",
                "description": "description2",
            },
            {
                "title": "title3",
                "description": "description "with quotes" in the middle",
            },
        ]
    }
}";
```

I am trying to use DeserializeObject with it

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Ideally, I would like all three items in my deserialised object, but even two would be better than the DeserializeObject just blowing up because the JSON is badly formatted.

Is there a possible correction which can be applied? I have looked at regexes but it's difficult to come up with something that could work with long and complex examples with many more items than this simplified version.

Comment: 1) Is the JSON formatted with different properties on different lines, as shown in the question, or is it all on one line?  If each property is on a separate line you *might* be able to come up with a heuristic to fix the string properties.  2) This might be a duplicate of [How can I deserialize an invalid json ? Truncated list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36576928/3744182)

Comment: It's not on one line. It's prettified with new lines and tabs. They could be removed fairly easily.

Comment: It may be helpful to keep them.  Since `\n` characters can never appear inside a string literal according to https://json.org/, you might be able to use `\n` as a "hint" for when a string literal is *really* terminated, and whip up a regex or something similar to preprocess the JSON and properly escape the embedded string literals.  You might need to maintain some sort of state machine to track whether you're in an object or an array....