# Newtonsoft.Json skip invalid objects, continue deserializing

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

How to skip/ignore/handle invalid json objects in Newtonsoft JSON?

Let's say we have string like:

```
[{
    "$id": "xc1",
    "sdfdsgds0sdfsadgdxc,sfgsagdfgdsfdm",
    "gxcgdfs"
}, {
    "$id": "2",
    "Property1": "Value",
    "Property2": "Value2"
}]
```

While doing

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
```

So the first object is invalid but I would like to read second valid one, but I've got JsonReaderException, is there a way to achieve ignoring/skipping invalid objects in array and go further with deserialization?

Comment: does this answer your question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107656/ignore-parsing-errors-during-json-net-data-parsing

Comment: Might be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576928/how-can-i-deserialize-an-invalid-json-truncated-list-of-objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore parsing errors during JSON.NET data parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107656/ignore-parsing-errors-during-json-net-data-parsing)

Comment: First approach bubble the problem as well for collection so the whole collection is null.

Comment: It's not easy when the JSON itself is **malformed** (which it is in your case), rather than just invalid for the current deserialization target.  `JsonTextReader` is a state machine that maintains the current token type and a set of valid transitions, and if the JSON token stream does not conform to the [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) the parser will not know what to expect next.  (In your case there is a property name but no value).  Continuing onward becomes problematic in such situations.

Comment: Hello @dbc is that you? What have you meant in last comment? https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1580

Comment: In that case the JSON is well-formed but not valid for the model being deserialized.  As such, it's possible to create a `JsonConverter` that screens out invalid values.  In your case the JSON is malformed (upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ to confirm) so a converter can't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have use JsonSerializerSettings class for determine errors while getting serialize JSON string.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = (obj, args) =>
    {
        var contextErrors = args.ErrorContext;
        contextErrors.Handled = true;
    }
};
var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
List<ViewModel> viewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<viewModel>>(result, settings);
```

Comment: This will set the collection to null, it won't get a second item.

Comment: You have make view model for constant JSON object. In my case my model is

public class ViewModel
{
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

If mentioned properties was not found, then that properties will be excluded.

Comment: The object won't be even created. First object will throw 2 errors one for invalid object second for collection, but I don't see the way to continue deserializing.